# jQuery: jRumble Plugin Pulse effect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-animate

I'm using the jRumble plugin on an image in a wrapped absolute positioned div (as suggested)

```
#headertitle is the absolute positioned div
#twitch is the image id
```

jRumble Plugin: Please see http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/ Demo 20

I'm having a hard time getting Demo 20 (Pulse) to work. The effect I'm getting is more like Demo 16 (Constant). The only way I can get the effect to work at all is using the below code:

```
$(function(){
$('#headertitle').jrumble();

    $('#twitch').trigger('startRumble');
    setTimeout(demoStop, 200);

    $('#twitch').trigger('stopRumble');
    setTimeout(demoStart, 200);
});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code in the page you provided, I observed that you haven't define the function `demoStart` and `demoStop`, so you are getting errors in the console, and not the desired result. Change your code to something like this:

```
$(function(){
   $('#headertitle').jrumble();
   var demoStart = function(){
       $('#twitch').trigger('startRumble');
       setTimeout(demoStop, 300);
   };

   var demoStop = function(){
       $('#twitch').trigger('stopRumble');
       setTimeout(demoStart, 300);
   };

   demoStart();
});
```

I've tested this code in your site (via the console) and it works.

Comment: That's it. Thanks for taking a look at it and helping me out.